# What is the Difference C#

Tags: c#

I am new to C#.
In Form Design let's say I have a Textbox, Listview and a button.
I write code for the button like this:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
```

... which would just add the text from the Textbox into the ListView.

Another way would be:

I created a Person.cs class and in there I add this

```
string FirstName;
public string FN {
    get { return FirstName; }
    set { FirstName = value; }
}
```

And on the button I add this:

```
Student NewStudent = new Student();
NewStudent.FN = textBox1.Text;
listBox1.Items.Add(NewStudent.FN);
```

These two would do exactly the same thing.
The first one only requires one line of code, but the second is several lines. Why not just use the first one which requires only one line?

Comment: Pick up a good book on object-oriented design. Textboxes shouldn't be used as variables.

Answer (score 6):

Because you might want to structure your program's data in appropriate objects instead of remembering that a single `Student` has its first name in `textBox1.Text`, its last name in `textBox4.Text`, and its age in `numericUpDown15.Value`. It gets messier when you have two students on the form, each with its own name, but in different text boxes (was student 1's name in `textBox7` or `textBox15`?). Generally I'd say you should avoid that.

When you use data objects you also have the freedom of using them when you don't have your GUI available, such as in backend code, while parsing data from a file, etc. Putting things into text boxes just to work with them sounds a bit cumbersome, right?

If you go that route (with data objects) you may also want to use data binding, which tells input and display controls where they get their data from. You could bind your text box directly to the `FN` property of the `Student` instance and you wouldn't have to write any code that makes the value update happen. You can likewise tell the list box that it should display the value of the `FN` property when you put the `Student` instances into the list directly (or you could just bind the list box to a collection of students).

You could also model your `Student` class like this:

```
class Student
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; } }
}
```

and then bind two text boxes to `FirstName` and `LastName`, while the list box displays `FullName`.

Answer (score 1):

They don't do the same thing at all.  The visible effect may be the same, but that's not the whole story.

What you are doing in the second example is creating a new object of type Student.  In the majority of situations, this class won't just contain a FirstName field, but will probably include all sorts of other information about the student.  Also, you are reasonably likely to then add the new Student object to a collection I order to do some more meaningful processing later on.  (E.g. Add a Course object to which students could subscribe, or a collection of Grade objects tied in to the students in some way.

Which is the "right" way to do this depends entirely on what you want your program to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but the one liner is absoulutely legit. The sesond approach makes sense in a scenario where you would have to store related data in memory, for example the last name additionally, so that your data is not spread all over the place. It would also allow the easy creation of lists of that (related) data.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use User FirstName on form 2 where `textbox.text` is not available then you might need someway to hold the information. That is where you need to use structure data object.

Having proper entity of a user allowed to hold many users at a time using List but having textboxes for multiple user is not a good idea.

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; } }
}
```

This is just one advantage of millions of proper object oriented code.